# Permission regarding Android EMM

Tags: android, permissions, device-policy-manager, emm

I am making an EMM application. This application will only be installed in firm's devices only. Is there any way to grant below permissions programmatically through **DevicePolicyManager**.

1. android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (Display over other apps)
2. android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE (Accessibility service)
3. android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS (Ignore battery optimization)

I want to grant above permissions through **DevicePolicyManager** as my app is a system owner app. But, I can't grant them through **devicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState**. As I have also tried **devicePolicyManager.setPermittedAccessibilityServices** for granting **ACCESSIBILY_SERVICE** programmatically, but it also didn't work. So, is there is any way I can grant above all permissions programmatically without navigating to that screen and turn in on manually. Or Is there is a way so that user cannot be able to disable the above features anyway. Like when I enable location and other permissions through **DevicePolicyManager** user is unable to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

So reviewing: https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#4.2.-runtime-permission-grant-state-management_1

and https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#permissionpolicy

seem to indicate at you can create a policy which will automatically grant permissions.

I do see:
[PERMISSION_POLICY_AUTO_GRANT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#PERMISSION_POLICY_AUTO_GRANT)

> Permission policy to always grant new permission requests for runtime permissions. Already granted or denied permissions are not affected by this.

and

[PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED)

> Runtime permission state: The permission is granted to the app and the user cannot manage the permission through the UI.

which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a permission policy or link so that I can grant above permissions programmatically.

Comment: @Ranjan Sorry I don't have direct experience. The existing developer documentation https://developers.google.com/android/management/introduction appears to cover the entire flow: https://developers.google.com/android/work/dev-options